# Select all columns with match prefix column name in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  charttime,
  id,
  gender,
  lm_*,
  vs_*
FROM `project-id.dataset.table`;
```

How do I select column with match prefix `lm_` and `vs_`?

Answer (score 1):

It gets the list of available column name in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and then use that as query.

```
-- this will returning string ("lm_foo, lm_bar, vs_foo,...")
DECLARE dynamic_columns STRING;

-- The result of query that filter match prefix will be stored in the dynamic_columns as string.
SET dynamic_columns = (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name) 
  FROM `project-id.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE column_name LIKE 'lm_%' OR column_name LIKE 'vs_%'
);


-- execute the original query with the result of dynamic_columns that has been stored
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT
  charttime,
  id,
  gender,
''' || dynamic_columns || '''
FROM `project-id.dataset.table`
''';
```